# Как показывать exit code после закрытия программы?

Tags: gcc, mingw, g++

Компилирую программы в windows cmd при помощи mingw g++. Каждый раз после закрытия программы хочу видеть exit code. Например, когда я использую ide clion, в котором использую mingw, после успешного завершения программы я вижу следующую надпись в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если, например программа завершилась не удачна, то вижу другую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть я вижу код с которым программа завершила своё выполнение.

Если я компилирую ту же самую программу, также при помощи mingw, но только в cmd. В не зависимости от успешности результата я не буду видеть код, с которым завершилась программа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы я видел это самый exit code в cmd ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой способ.

На самом деле, сам по себе вопрос [не нов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line/11476681#11476681).

Всё сводится к использованию переменной `%errorlevel%`

приблизительно в таком коде:

```
    start /wait something.exe
    echo %errorlevel%
```

То есть, если сделать себе какой то exec.bat с таким содержимым:

```
    echo off
    start /wait %1
    echo %errorlevel%
```

то при завершении программы будет показываться код завершения.

Comment: Огромное спасибо !)